# Cómo saber si un subinforme está vacío

Tags: crystal-reports

Estoy trabajando con Crystal Reports. Tengo un informe principal, y en una subsección hay un subinforme, siendo el subinforme de el único contenido de la subsección.

Necesito que la subsección no se muestre en el caso de que el subinforme esté vacío. ¿Cómo puedo controlar desde las fórmulas de informe principal si el subinforme está vacío?

Un saludo.

Comment: Sería más completa tu pregunta si añades el código con el que estás trabajando explicando hasta dónde has llegado y qué problema en concreto te impide avanzar.

Answer (score 1):

En el reporte principal, busca la sección donde colocaste el sub-reporte. Da un clic derecho y selecciona la opción **Section Expert**, en las opciónes mostradas, selecciona la opcion **Suppress Blank Section**. Selecciona Aceptar y Aceptar.
[image: Section Expert]

Dentro del sub reporte. Si tienes campos fijos (Formulas, labels), vas a colocar una formula en todos los campos. Clic derecho al campo, Agrega la formula en la opción **Suppress**. En la formula vas a comparar algún campo que regrese tu consulta del sub-reporte. Ejemplo

```
 IF isnull({sp_qbxselem;1.articulo})
THEN
    TRUE
ELSE 
    FALSE
```

Debes realizar esto para todos los campos del sub-reporte.